# Replace " - " with whitespaces using regexp in Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string and I need to replace `'.'`, `'_'` and `'-'` characters with whitespaces. The code below works just fine.

```
String value = "my-test-is-here.and.here_and_even-here";
value = value.replaceAll("[\\._-]", " ");
```

My issue is that in a string like this `"my test - your text"` I need to keep a dash surrounded by whitespaces (`' - '`) unchanged. I tried to use look ahead and look behind like this

```
"[\\._((?<!\\s)-(?!\\s)){1}]"
```

but I'm getting the following exception.

```
01-15 08:45:12.786: E/AndroidRuntime(25950): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: In a character range [x-y], x is greater than y near index 14:
01-15 08:45:12.786: E/AndroidRuntime(25950): [\._((?<!\s)-(?!\s)){1}]
01-15 08:45:12.786: E/AndroidRuntime(25950):               ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I ended up with the following expression, which perfectly fulfilled my needs.

```
"[._]|(?<!\\s)-(?!\\s)|(-$)|(^-)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your *lookahead and lookbehind assertions* outside of your [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
value = value.replaceAll("[._]|(?<!\\s)-(?!\\s)", " ");
```

Comment: OP want the dash surrounding with white space to be not matched. With that regex, it actually will match the dash.

Comment: My bad you're right.. I was testing without removing the backslash in an normal regex tester.

Comment: This is what I initially did, just a quick note for OP (I assume it won't matter..but (s)he should know): this will ***not*** match/replace the hyphen in `foo -bar` (since it has a whitespace before it), even though it is not *surrounded* by whitespace.

Comment: @Sam @hwnd Thanks guys. It works just fine. I had a special case `foo -` case, where `-` was at the end of the string, and I handled it too. Updated expression is in the question.